# java error: the file cannot be validated as the host "www.getahead.ltd.uk" is currently unreachable

Tags: java, ajax, dwr

I am using eclipse, Java, and seting up Ajax-DWR. When I run my program nothing happens. I belive This is cause by warning in my xml file. I tried looking on google but didn't found any  thing.

**files Path, jar files, etc...**

Take a look at the attached image.

[image]

**I am getting a following warning / error in DWR.XML File**

> The file cannot be validated as the host "www.getahead.ltd.uk" is currently unreachable.

**DWR.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<!DOCTYPE dwr PUBLIC "-//GetAhead Limited//DTD Direct Web Remoting 2.0//EN"
    "http://www.getahead.ltd.uk/dwr/dwr20.dtd">
<dwr>
  <allow>
    <create creator="new" javascript="ex01">
      <param name="class" value="DWR.ex01"/>
    </create>
  </allow>
</dwr>
```

**ex01.HTML File**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/interface/ex01Script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/engine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/util.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ex01.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p> Name: <input type="text" id="demoName"/>
  <input value="Send" type="button" onclick="update()"/> <br/>
  Reply: <span id="demoReply"></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**ex01.JAVA File**

```
package DWR;

public class ex01 {
public String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Hello, " + name;
    }
}
```

**ex01.JS File**

```
function update() {
    name = dwr.util.getValue("demoName");

    ex01Script.sayHello(name, updateData);
}

function updateData(data) {
    dwr.util.setValue("demoReply", data);
}
```

Comment: That warning is just Eclipse telling you it can't download the schema (XSD) in order to tell you if the elements you have in your XML is valid.  It is almost certainly harmless.